# Establishing the convergence or divergence of the sequences $(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Establish the convergence or the divergence of the sequence $$(x_n) = \frac{(-1)^n n}{n+1}$$

At the moment all I can conclude is that $$(x_n) = \frac{(-1)^n n}{n+1} < (-1)^n\left(\frac{n}{n}\right) = (-1)^n$$

So $(x_n)$ is bounded above by $1$ and below by $-1$. How can I show that $(x_n)$ is convergent or isn't convergent?

Comment: The sequence is oscillating between two subsequences, one converging to $-1$ and one converging to $1$. Hence, there is no limit.

Comment: Your conclusion $x_n < (-1)^n$ may be false. Can you see why?

Comment: @GEdgar, No why would it be false?

Comment: When $n=1$, your inequality $x_n < (-1)^n$ says $-\frac{1}{2} < -1$, which is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, since it isn't. The subsequence $(x_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $1$, whereas the subsequence $(x_{2n-1})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see
that the sequence diverges
is to note that

$\begin{array}\\
x_{2n}-x_{2n+1}
&=\frac{(-1)^{2n} 2n}{2n+1}-\frac{(-1)^{2n+1} 2n+1}{2n+2}\\
&=\frac{2n}{2n+1}+\frac{ 2n+1}{2n+2}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2n+1}+1-\frac{ 1}{2n+2}\\
&=2-\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{ 1}{2n+2}\\
&\gt 1
\qquad\text{for }n \ge 1\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
it can not converge.

Answer (score 0):

The above series is divergent. It is true that it is bounded from -1 to 1 (it actually oscillates between -1 and 1), however the term "convergence" means that after a big number of steps (ergo n tends to infinity) then the series gives a unique value.

In this case it does not, since it gives 1 or -1 (if n is even or odd), therefor it is divergent. Hope that it helps you out! :)

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of the sequence's end behavior:

$\frac {n}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}\to 1\neq 0 \qquad \text{as} \ \ n \to \infty$

Approaches 1, and bounded above and below by $\pm \left (1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$.  The sequence would then $\to (-1)^n$ as n gets larger.   Thus diverges in a similar manner to sine or cosine